# Неопределенная ссылка на функцию

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код main

```
#include "draw.h"
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    init();
    while (key != KEY_Q) {
        Draw();
        rk_readkey(&key);
        switch (key) {
        case KEY_UP:
            K_UP();
            break;
        case KEY_DOWN:
            K_DOWN();
            break;
        case KEY_RIGHT:
            K_RIGHT();
            break;
        case KEY_LEFT:
            K_LEFT();
            break;
        case KEY_F5:
            F5();
            break;
        case KEY_F6:
            F6();
            break;
        case KEY_L:
            load();
            break;
        case KEY_S:
            save();
            break;
        case KEY_R:
            break;
        case KEY_I:
        init();
        case KEY_Q:
        break;
        case KEY_T:
            break;
        case KEY_OTHER:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

вот код draw
#ifndef DRAW_H
#define DRAW_H
#include "bigChars.h"
#include "myReadkey.h"
#include "func.h"
#include "myTerm.h"

```
int num_element;
void init();
void clean_input();
void save();
void load();
void move(int i);
void K_UP();
void K_DOWN();
void K_RIGHT();
void K_LEFT();
void K_ENTER();
void F5();
void F6();
void Draw();

#endif
```

Почему пишет такую ошибку и как можно исправить?

Comment: Нужно либо реализовать функцию в прикрепленном коде, либо дать дополнительно линкеру или среде obj или lib файл с реализацией этих функций. Где ваша реализация? Я не вижу тут реализацию функций (той же `void F5() {  где код функции? };`)

Comment: Что должны делать все эти функции? Вы хотели сделать их пока пустыми?